# Dismissing side menu by tapping anywhere

Tags: swift, view, dismiss, side-menu

I created a side menu using a container view. It slides in the main view each time i press a menu.
You can find my project here:
https://github.com/marybnq/side-menu

I need to dismiss it by tapping anywhere in the mainVC. 
How do I do it?

Comment: You can use TapGestures and check when tapped mainVc change constant of side bar

Comment: Right now you can dismiss it by clicking on menu - correct?

Comment: @JVS yes, why???

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik yes but I should pass data between vc and I'm not sure about how to pass the sideMenuConstraint to the other vc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var menuConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var sideMenuOpen = false
var gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(toggleSideMenu), name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)


    gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.toggleSideMenu))

}
@objc func toggleSideMenu() {
    if sideMenuOpen {
        sideMenuOpen = false
        menuConstraint.constant = -240
        self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture!)
    } else {
        sideMenuOpen = true
        menuConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture!)
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Perfect! What if I want it to work in other view controllers? I used the Notification Center to pass the toggleSideMenu func but it doesn’t add the gesture

Comment: I tried to create the project from the beginning and now it works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple:
 1. Add tap gesture to view of mainVC and disable it by default
 2. Enable tap gesture on showing side menu, to handle taps
 3. Disable tap gesture on hiding side menu